# Boxshadow not working on :hover but does in other one

Tags: html, css, layout

I cannot get these div's to display the box-shadow when I hover over another div. I got it working in a Jsfiddle but when applied to these div's it doesn't work and I don't know why. I have included both the original (working) Jsfiddle and this (non-working version) for comparison. I don't understand why it's not working since the only difference is that they have different class and id names.

Below is my current code:

CSS:

```
.SideContainer {
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;

    background-color: #4274aa;
    opacity: 0.6;

}

    .SideContainer h1 {
        color: white;
    }

    .SideContainer a {
        margin: 321px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    background-color: #05337e;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.LeftSide {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

    .LeftSide:hover ~ #TLHOOK , .LeftSide:hover ~ #BLHOOK {
    /* Sided box-shadow */
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px -7px #111, -6px 0px 10px -7px #111;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<section id="ServicesGroup">
    <div class="Centered">
        <!-- Let the magic happen. -->
        <section id="TLHOOK" class="LeftSide SideContainer">
            <div class="TopHeadingShell">
                <img src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/HTML5LogoWithWhiteText.png" />
                <h1>sdsd</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="TRHOOK" class="RightSide SideContainer">
            <div class="TopHeadingShell">
                <img src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/GearsIcon.png" />
                <h1>sdsd</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="ServicesGroupExtended">
    <div class="Centered">
        <!-- Let the magic happen. -->
        <section id="BLHOOK" class="LeftSide SideContainer">
            <a href="~/Shared/Services/sdsd">Packages &amp; Pricing</a>
        </section>
        <section class="Bottom MiddleContainer">
            <h2>
                something here
            </h2>
            <br />
            <a href="~/Shared/About">Learn More</a>
        </section>
        <section id="BRHOOK" class="RightSide SideContainer">
            <a href="~/Shared/Services/sdsd">Packages &amp; Pricing</a>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

Here is the [working](http://jsfiddle.net/h944n/6/) JSFiddle and the [non-working](http://jsfiddle.net/UgKMZ/) (the one I need to work) one. Please don't mind the positioning in the last example - just hover over the first div that you see and you'll see that it doesn't work in the second example I linked to.

Why isn't this working as expected? I mean, the only different is that the class names and id names have changed, and like, I would've thought it would work?

Answer (score 2):

`#TLHOOK` is not a sibling of `.Left` (it is the same element) therefore the `~` selector can't be used in this context.

In your working example, `#one`, `#two` and `#three` are siblings.

> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the element itself than the sibling in CSS

```
.LeftSide:hover ~ #TLHOOK , .LeftSide:hover ~ #BLHOOK
```

IT should be

```
.LeftSide:hover ~ #TRHOOK , .LeftSide:hover ~ #BRHOOK {
```

Also you wont see the box-shadow working after the above fix as you have given .LeftSide float:left.

So I have given float: right to  .SideContainer and also increased the box shadow just to make the box shadow visible.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/UgKMZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using the [`~` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/). The `~` selector selects the element preceded by the current element, and in your second chunk there is a `section` between the two elements.

```
<section id="TLHOOK"> <!-- This doesn't precede anything -->
<section id="TRHOOK"> <!-- This precedes TLHOOK -->

<section id="BLHOOK"> <!-- This doesn't precede anything -->
<section class="MiddleContainer">
<section id="BRHOOK"> <!-- This precedes MiddleContainer, not BLHOOK -->
```

In order to fix this you'll need to use a second `~`:

```
..., .LeftSide:hover ~ section ~ #BRHOOK { ... }
```

This selects the preceding #BLHOOK of the preceding section. It's pretty hacky, but it does the trick!

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uSFu2/).